# Why do I need to do a manual driver update in 2011?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers

It seems drivers updates for Windows 7 are still not 100% automated.

When I check the driver for my video card - Nvidia GeForce GTX 460 - via the device manager, it says the driver is up to date, with date 20 May 2011. When I search via Nvidia's support, I find [this driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7-winvista-64bit-280.26-whql-driver.html) from August 2011, which is newer.

Why are there still delays in getting drivers pushed automatically nowadays? Is it because the driver is "relatively new" - two months old? I've had similar issues with older drivers as well.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the NVIDIA driver you have is approved by [WHQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing).  The one on the manufacturer site is newer, but hasn't finished the approval process yet.

Comment: This - Windows Update doesn't just let manufacturers throw new drivers onto it willy-nilly.  I personally don't recommend updating drivers period anyway *unless they're addressing some problem you have or adding some feature you want*.  Video card drivers especially are notorious for new releases to up the framerate on the latest, greatest game - which would be fine if they were adequately tested for bugs, but they're not.  You can cause more trouble than you fix.

Comment: tl;dr - If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: That depends.  Sometimes a newer driver fixes bugs or performance issues that you don't even know you have.

Comment: That's true, but if it's a bug that *isn't actually causing you any grief* (which it probably isn't if you're unaware of it), it's IMO not worth the risk.  YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 1):

For things like video cards the chipset may be nVidia (or whoever) but the card is made by a third party.  That is who needs to make the driver available.  They also may make minor changes to the fucntion and so need a unique driver.  See this often for nVidia cards that come in Dell laptops.  nVidia notes that only the Dell driver should be used. As @Nighthawk notes there are other factors as well.  I have found that even if MS posts a video driver, it may not work due to changes made by the maker of the card.

Checking the maufacturer site for a driver once in a while is not too hard.  Later Dell and Lenovo (probably others) hardware provide an app that works likle Windows update but for their hardware and drivers.